# MFRC522 minor problems

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, rfid

I'm working on a small project for a presentation. My goal is to read the UID of multiple Mifare Classic cards and compare it to a hardcoded list for different actions. All is well (the reading and comparing part that is) but 2 small problems that I have encountered are:

- The first (maybe up to three, since the reader is a little bit on the fast side) read after uploading my code will return a UID of just 0s and a wrong PICC type.
- After reading a PICC and then trying to read another, the reader prints the UID / PICC Type of the reader before, which is kinda not helpful when trying to light LEDs based on UID.

Here is my sketch:

```
/*
HEADER TEXT
GOES HERE
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup()
{
  // Serielles Interface initialisieren
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // SPI initialisieren
  SPI.begin();

  mfrc522.PCD_Init();

  // Für später
  // pinMode (2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // Eigene UID bilden. Dazu nehmen wir die 4(7)Byte Hex UID aus Block 0 und quetschen sie in einen schönen String.
  String uID = String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3],HEX);

  // PICC Typen
  byte piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);

  // Nach neuen Karten suchen.
  delay(250);
  if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    delay(250);
    mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial();

    // Debug Ausgabe
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Die Kartennummer lautet: ");
    Serial.print(uID);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Picc Type: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));
    Serial.println();

    // Überprüfe auf unterstützten PICC Typ und noch mehr Debug Kram
    if ( piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI && piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K&& piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K) {
      Serial.println("Diese Tech-Demo benötigt MIFARE Classic Karten.");
      return;
    }

    // Den UID String Verglichen und eine entsprechende Aktion ausführen
    if(uID=="myUIDforStuff") {
      Serial.println("Access granted");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on - "the reader prints the UID / PICC Type of the reader before"? It looks like you are doing that in your code, not the reader

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
HEADER TEXT
GOES HERE
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup()
{
  // Serielles Interface initialisieren
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // SPI initialisieren
  SPI.begin();

  mfrc522.PCD_Init();

  // Für später
  // pinMode (2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // Eigene UID bilden. Dazu nehmen wir die 4(7)Byte Hex UID aus Block 0 und quetschen sie in einen schönen String.
// String uID = String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3],HEX);

  // PICC Typen
// byte piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);

  // Nach neuen Karten suchen.
  delay(250);
  if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    delay(250);
    mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial();
     // Eigene UID bilden. Dazu nehmen wir die 4(7)Byte Hex UID aus Block 0 und quetschen sie in einen schönen String.
 String uID = String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2],HEX)+String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3],HEX);

  // PICC Typen
 byte piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);


    // Debug Ausgabe
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Die Kartennummer lautet: ");
    Serial.print(uID);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Picc Type: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));
    Serial.println();





    // Überprüfe auf unterstützten PICC Typ und noch mehr Debug Kram
    if ( piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_MINI && piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K&& piccType != MFRC522::PICC_TYPE_MIFARE_1K) {
      Serial.println("Diese Tech-Demo benötigt MIFARE Classic Karten.");
      return;
    }

    // Den UID String Verglichen und eine entsprechende Aktion ausführen
    if(uID=="myUIDforStuff") {
      Serial.println("Access granted");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: An answer with just code, without any explanation is not sufficient! Could you please clarify what you have changed in OP source code?